# Set default radio button to check in laravel vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, v-model

I'm having a trouble on how can I check  the radio button when the `v-models` is empty, . If the value of my `formfields.status` is empty the radio button should automatically checked. Is there anyway trick how to implement it?

*This is status value looks like in my dev tools extension when `status` value is empty*

[image]

This is what I've tried but nothing works, thanks in advance!.

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
   <label class="radio mr-2">
       <input class="details-input" type="radio" name="status_radio"  value="1" v-model="formFields.status" :checked="formFields.status == null"/> Active
     </label>
       <label class="radio">
          <input class="details-input" type="radio" name="status_radio" value="0" v-model="formFields.status"/> Inactive 
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `formFields.status == ''`

Comment: @Nigel Ren  Yes I already tried that but it doesn't work but when I removed my `v-model` it checked the radio button I guess v-model restrict any kind of checked or dropdown is there any way for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

V-model is working with the checked property of radio buttons, so setting that on your own as well might result in faulty behaviour.
When you're using V-model, you'd expect the UI to be always in sync with the data. Note that the "empty selection" state is invalid for radio buttons, there should be one always selected. If you wanted to allow empty selection using an optional select field would be better from UX perspective as well.
So, the easiest way to fix it is disallowing the empty state for your model by providing a default value to the status field, which would control which radio button should be checked by default.
In short:

- use "status: 1" in your data to set the default value
- remove the :checked bindings from the template

Comment: thanks for your response but I didn't get the idea , I tried different ways but the the output always the same